# Nifi: Check CSV file for row updates, then ingest

Tags: csv, apache-nifi, data-ingestion

Usually in our environment, when someone has new data to be ingested, they generate a new CSV file, which Nifi will pick up from an SFTP. However I have a new case where the source's CSV file sits on a shared drive and their application adds new rows to it when there are updates.

Is there a way that Nifi can monitor this CSV file for when new rows have been added? And can it subsequently ingest only the new data? I think it has something like this for relational databases, but I haven't seen anything similar for files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `TailFile` processor for this. If the rows are always appended to the end (which I suspect is the case) then depending on how it is scheduled (and how many rows are added at a time) TailFile should output either one line per flowfile or a number of lines per flowfile. In either case you will have a stream of new rows.